# Background color of quiverkey in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I define the background color of a [quiverkey](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiverkey) added to a quiver plot in `matplotlib`? 
In the following example, how can I make it white in order to have it more readable (even if it overrides part of the figure)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random

numpy.random.seed(2)
x,y = numpy.meshgrid(range(11), range(11))
u,v = numpy.random.randn(101), numpy.random.randn(101)

qv = plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
plt.quiverkey(qv, .5, 0.8, 5, 'Where is my background?', coordinates='axes',
              fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'}, color='r', labelcolor='g')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the background color in the text attribute of the quiverkey using the `set_backgroundcolor` function. A complete example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.random

numpy.random.seed(2)
x,y = numpy.meshgrid(range(11), range(11))
u,v = numpy.random.randn(101), numpy.random.randn(101)

qv = plt.quiver(x,y,u,v)
qk = plt.quiverkey(qv, .5, 0.8, 5, 'Here is my background', coordinates='axes',
              fontproperties={'weight': 'bold'}, color='r', labelcolor='g')
t = qk.text.set_backgroundcolor('w')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ed Smith. This however could cause trouble since the key arrow is not included in this manipulation (has no background), and could for example be overlayed by the text background if the `labelsep` is too low... Any idea how to work on the text *and* arrow together (without having to use a `Rectangle` patch...)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `quiverkey` is an artist which contains a `text`  and `vector` object. The text object has an associated transparent `bbox` which, by calling `set_backgroundcolor`, can be changed to a colour (this processes is not adding a new rectangle patch). You can probably change the `qk.text.set_zorder`/`qk.vector.set_zorder` to move the text below the arrow if there is a problem with overlap.

Comment: Sorry, the arrow is a quiver object `qk.Q` so the order can be changed by `qk.Q.set_zorder`. I don't think there are any methods to change the background for the `quiverkey` artist object as a whole...

Comment: Thanks @Ed Smith. I was hoping for a solution where the `quiverkey` as a whole could be backgrounded (the only solution I had in mind was placing a rectangle patch behind - which is indeed not was you propose), but it seems it doesn't exist... That said, I don't seem to be able to change the `zorder` of the arrow, would you post the example (you can use `labelsep=0.03` in the `quiverkey` to make this apparent) or post a link to the documentation? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ztl, the `zorder` does not appear to work in `quiverkey` as expected (maybe a bug?) I think your best bet would be to draw a rectangle manually if you need it ensure both arrow and text are clear...

Comment: I thought adding spaces in front of the label text and setting the positon to 'E' would overlap the background behind the quiver, but it didn't work `plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.5, 0.8, 5, '             extra label space', labelpos='E')`